não consigo inserir dados em SQLite
Estou aprendendo SQLite.
Fiz uma tabela de Preco e livros com os elementos:
CREATE TABLE Preco(
    PrecoCompra float,
    Precovenda float,
    IdLivros SMALLINT,
    Foreign Key(IdLivros) REFERENCES Livros(IdLivro)
); 

CREATE TABLE Livros(
    NomeLivro varchar[50],
    IdLivro SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
    PrecoVenda float
);


Criei para testar as Keys dos Bancos de dados, porém anteriormente na tabela Preco eu usei o NomeLivro como foreign key, vi que estava errado então dei um DROP TABLE Preco, já que não tinha nenhum dado na tabela, corrigi colocando o foreign key no IdLivro.
Porém quando vou inserir algum dado na tabela preco, de vez puxar o IdLivro, ele mantém o NomeLivro.
Por que isso acontece? sendo que eu apaguei a antiga tabela, não deveria ter apagado todas colunas junto?

Não estava com cache na aplicação? Dependo do aplicativo que está rodando o banco (caso haja interface), pode ser necessário fechar e abrir novamente para atualizar as informações de exibição

Realmente era isso, vou pesquisar se tem como atualizar sem precisar fechar a janela, utilizo o DBeaver se por acaso já souber como fazer isso. Ademais muito obrigado pela ajuda
